# setVisible() efficiency

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I was wondering, would it be more efficient to do something like this:

```
   setVisible(false) // if the component is invisible
```

or like this:

```
   if(isVisible()){
      setVisible(false)
   }
```

Comment: Well It depends on your logic... If you just want to hide the element then use 1st statement or if you want to check whether element is visible then hide then use 2nd

Comment: There's no logic difference here. Just a superfluous if in the second case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with efficiency. Use the first one, it's simpler and probably already contains the visibility check inside the setVisible() method.

When you write code, don't try to think about efficiency, especially in ridiculously trivial cases like this. You're running on a multi GHz computer, so you're only wasting your time on micro-optimization like this.

Comment: Alright, that's what I really wanted to know. I'm just paranoid since my teacher likes to take off points for code redundancy.

Answer (score 3):

`setVisible()` as implemented by [JComponent](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JComponent.java#JComponent.setVisible%28boolean%29) already calls `isVisible()` so it's not more efficient to add a redundant call. In any case, it would be really improbable that it would be any kind of a performance bottle neck.

Answer (score 0):

The only case in which your second example would make sense, is in a case of switching visibility on and off.

```
if(isVisible()){
   setVisible(false);
}else{
   setVisible(true);
}
```